# GoDaddy A record and SSL Handshake error

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, ssl-certificate, godaddy

I have pointed A record to my server IP  in GOoDaddty as ns1.example.com and it is working.But I am confused with SSL error. I have generated SSL certificate with CN as ns1.example.com. When I try to connect to the server I get an error **SSL handshake error**. Is it like I need to setup DNS server on my server or it is ok with above setting. I generated certificates correctly. Is it like localhost in server != ns1.example.com thats why ssl is failing? how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It should be ok with above setting. Just make sure that you are reaching the correct IP (DNS being correctly propagated) and check with a DNS checker or openssl client the reason of the SSL hanshake error

Comment: It is giving " no peer certificate available."
"No client certificate CA names sent"
Any Idea?

Comment: probably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457408/openssl-command-to-check-if-a-server-is-presenting-a-certificate